# Flying balloon with a parabolic animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made a simple animation of a balloon moving from left to right side of the screen, but I want to make it as a parabolic movement instead of linear animation. Also I want to hide it from left site instead of starting on left:0;

Here's my actual code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function loop() {
    $('#promo').css({
      left: 0
    });
    $('#promo').animate({
      left: '+=100%',
    }, 10000, 'linear', function() {
      loop();
    });
  }

  loop();
});
```

```css
#promo {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 500;
  left: 0px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="promo">
  <img border="0" alt="promo balloon" src="http://www.placehold.it/50" />
</div>
```

Comment: if you change "left" to - the width of your balloon in your javascript, you will have it starting from offscreen.

Comment: Thanks! @Jan_dh first problem solved:)! updated left to {left:-199} and now works perfectly!

Comment: A CSS animation or plain js would be less CPU consuming. A 10sec search on google bring me this: http://codepen.io/ajfarkas/pen/zmKlt Could be adpated to your use case i guess

Comment: You can do this using purely CSS3 animations, no javascript is required: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-name-property

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff you're right and that example is perfect!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the `left` property of the balloon to `-50px`, so it's not visible at the start of the animation.

Also, to stop the scrollbars appearing, give the container of the balloon `overflow: hidden`. You could then use jQuery/JavaScript to adjust the width of the container to fit the browser's viewport on document ready, and window resize.

**CSS**

```
.balloon-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px; // Set a height of your container here, or use jQuery/JavaScript
}

.balloon {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function sizeContainer() {
    $('.container').css('width', window.innerWidth);
  }

  function loop() {
    $('.balloon').css('left', '-50px');

    $('#promo').animate({
      left: '+=100%',
    }, 10000, 'linear', function() {
      loop();
    });
  }

  // Run initial functions.
  sizeContainer();
  loop();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    // Re-run functions on window resize.
    sizeContainer();
  });

});
```